# 'Angular is not defined'

Tags: angularjs

I have my files setup right now out of which one them is my index.html file and another is a app.javascript file. For some reason I keep getting error saying" Angular is not defined" which I unsure why as my script files look placed properly too. Below is how my index file and app.js file look like

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!Stylesheet>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!Javascript>

    <!-- load angular, nganimate, and ui-router -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<!MainAngularApp>

<body ng-app="OnboardingApp">

    <div class="container">

        <!Injecting all the views here>

        <div ui-view></div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

//Creating our Angular App injecting ngAnimate, UIRouter

```
angular.module('OnboardingApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

//Configuring the routes

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider



    //Route followed to show our form

    .state('form',{

        url:'/form',

        templateUrl: 'form.html',

        controller: 'formController'

    })



    //Nested States where each will have their own view



    //Nesting the sign up form

    .state('form.signup',{

        url:'/signup',

        templateURL:'form-signup.html'

    })



    //Nesting the Question form 

    .state('form.questions',{

        url:'/questions',

        templateUrl:'form-questions.html'

    })



    //Nesting the Finish form

     .state('form.finish',{

        url:'/finish',

        templateUrl:'form-finish.html'

    });



    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/signup');

})

.controller('formcontroller', function($scope){

    //Storing all the form data into the form data object

    $scope.formData= {};



    //Function to process form data

    $scope.processData = function(){

        alert('Sign up is successful')

    };



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define ng-app in your view so that angularjs app gets initiatied,

```
<div class="container" ng-app="OnboardingApp">
```

Comment: Does that mean the index.html file or the form view files which still have to be written by me?

Comment: yeah you need to do that